# How can I replace every letter in a string with opposite letter? C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

How can I replace every letter in a string with opposite letter? For example, replace "a" with "z", replace "B" with "Y". How can I make it for every string?

Comment: Though the idea is the same, can you make it clear is it a std::string or C-style string?

Comment: `if(letter == 'a') ... else if(letter == 'b') ...` would work.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. Did you try something? Do you have some code you could post?

Comment: Use two arrays, "a..z", and "z..a", the corresponding opposite will be in the second array and the indexes will be the same...

Comment: @FrankMancini that's overcomplicated, you can do the same with just a single array and using a modulus

Comment: Make a hash table for every letter as key and its opposite letter as value .then iterate over the string and get value for every letter and make the new string it will take O(n+1) time

Answer (score 2):

Please consider this solution:

From the ASCII table http://www.asciitable.com/

```
CHAR DECIMAL
"A"   65
"B"   66
...
"Y"   89
"Z"   90
```

If we want to swap 'B' (which is the second char past 'A') for 'Y' (which is the second to last char from 'Z'), we might want to" take the distance from 'A' and subtract that from 'Z', as in 'Z' - (x - 'A')

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

char invert_char(char x)
{
    if (x >= 'a' && x <= 'z')
        return char('a' -x + 'z');
    if (x >= 'A' && x <= 'Z')
        return char('A' -x + 'Z');

    return x;
}

std::string invert_string(std::string str)
{
    for (auto& c: str)
        c = invert_char(c);
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    std::string test = "ABCDEF UVWXYZ";
    std::cout << test << std::endl;
    std::cout << invert_string(test) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Then explain to me why the other user has to copy my answer on his?

Comment: That I don't know.

Comment: I have edited the answer and elaborated. Do you think I missed on something? Thank you for the feedback and allowing me to improve my answer.

Comment: the code `'a' + 'z'` will overflow since it's a `char` type. hence return a wrapped around value.

Comment: It is better now. You've explained the logic for finding the "opposite" letter before integrating that logic into the loop through the string. That's good.

Comment: Thanks acegs, I have added a fix.

Comment: Hmm... Perhaps: "If we want to swap 'B' (which is the second char past 'A') for 'Y' (which is the second to last char from 'Z'), we might want to" *take the distance from 'A' and subtract that from 'Z', as in `'Z' - (x - 'A')`*? Then either use this formula in your code or mention that removing the parentheses gives `'Z' - x  + 'A'`? (Just an idea; don't feel obligated to accept it.)

Comment: This probably works, but note that there is nothing in the question that says that the text is encoded in ASCII. That's usually the case these days, but there are [other encodings](http://www.astrodigital.org/digital/ebcdic.html) in use where this approach does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Use a translation/lookup array.

Define an array (vector) of source letters, and a translation string. You can use a pair of maps to to encode and decode, or you could use brute force string search for every character (both ways shown below.

```
class translate {

    std::string original;
    std::string coded;
    std::map<char,char> encode_map;
    std::map<char,char> decode_map;
```

translation function (brute force),

```
    public:

    // you could pass original and coded string pair, or use defaults
    translate() {
        original="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        coded="ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBAzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba";

        for( size_t ndx = 0; ndx < order; ++ndx ) {
            encode[original.at(ndx)] = coded.at(ndx);
            decode[coded.at(ndx)] = original.at(ndx);
        }
    }

    //brute force scans original to find coded position, n*O(m)
    std::string
    brute(std::string src)
    {
        std::string dest;
        for( auto& ch : src ) {
            dest.push_back(coded.at(find(original,ch)));
        }
        return dest;
    }

    //use map for encode, decode, n*O(log(m))
    std::string
    encode(std::string src)
    {
        std::string dest;
        for( auto& ch : src ) {
            dest.push_back(encode_map[ch]);
        }
        return dest;
    }

    std::string
    decode(std::string src)
    {
        std::string dest;
        for( auto& ch : src ) {
            dest.push_back(decode_map[ch]);
        }
        return dest;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[std::transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) provides a very convenient way to apply a transformation to every member of a container. With `std::string` you can easily apply your wanted transformation of grabbing the character from the opposite end of the alphabet by testing if the current character `isupper()` and if so, grab the character offset from `'Z'` the same number of characters as the current character is from `'A'`. (same would apply for `islower()` in case of a lowercase character)

If the character is not an alpha-character, then it remains unchanged. Using `std::transform`, your function can be reduced to:

```
void oppositechar (std::string& s)
{
    std::transform (s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(),
                    [](unsigned char c) { 
                        if (std::isupper(c))        /* if upper */
                            c = 'Z' - c + 'A';      /* replace w/dist from Z */
                        else if (std::islower(c))   /* if lower */
                            c = 'z' - c + 'a';      /* replace w/dist from z */
                        return c;
                    });
}
```

Adding a short program that lets you enter any string as the first argument on the command line (or using `"Hello World"` if no argument is provided), you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>

void oppositechar (std::string& s)
{
    std::transform (s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(),
                    [](unsigned char c) { 
                        if (std::isupper(c))        /* if upper */
                            c = 'Z' - c + 'A';      /* replace w/dist from Z */
                        else if (std::islower(c))   /* if lower */
                            c = 'z' - c + 'a';      /* replace w/dist from z */
                        return c;
                    });
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    std::string s = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "Hello World";

    std::cout << s << '\n';

    oppositechar (s);       /* transform s with encoding */

    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/transformoppositechar
Hello World
Svool Dliow

$ ./bin/transformoppositechar "ABC-XYZ abc-xyz"
ABC-XYZ abc-xyz
ZYX-CBA zyx-cba
```

Look things over and let me know if I did not understand what you were attempting to do correctly, or if you have further questions.

Comment: I mean for every letter in a string inputted, similarly, replace "d" with "w", and replace "E" with "V", and so on. Not only for the letters I've just mentioned.

Comment: Yes, yes, the above will do that for every character in your input. Whatever you pass to the function `oppositechar`, all alpha-characters will be encoded as you describe. Have you found a case where that doesn't work?

Comment: For example, if you enter `./bin/transformoppositechar ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` you will get `ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBAzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba` in return. Or if you enter `abCD1234EFgh` you get `zyXW1234VUts` in return. Or `My dog has 3 fleas. My cat has none.` you get `Nb wlt szh 3 uovzh. Nb xzg szh mlmv.`

Answer (score 1):

You can check for each letter in the input string and replace it with the opposite letter manually by writing if statements. But there's a more programmatic way.

In English alphabet there are only 26 letters. To get the inverse string, you will replace any a with z, any b with y. That means you replace 1st letter with 26th letter, 2nd letter with 25th letter. As programmers, we count from 0. So you replace 0th letter with 26th and so on. If the input letter is a, i.e 0th letter, you'll replace it with (26 - 0)th letter. If it is b, i.e 1st letter you'll replace it with (26 - 1)th letter and so on. If it is nth letter, replace it with (26 - n)th letter.

But in ascii table, a is 97th and A is 65th. So we have to substract 97 from ascii value of relevant letter before do the above explained math. Substract 65 if letter is upper case.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string inverse(string data){
  string inverse_string = "";

  for(char c : data){
    int limit = 97;

    if (((int)c) < 97) limit = 65; //assumes the letter is uppercase

    int chr_code = (int)c - limit;
    int inverse_chr_code = 26 - chr_code;
    int result = inverse_chr_code + (limit - 1);
    inverse_string += (char)result;
  }
  return inverse_string;
}

int main(){
  cout << inverse("apPle");
  return 0;

}
```

Above code gives output "zkKov" i.e the inverse string to "apPle"

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
char newChar = 'z' - (oldChar - 'a'); // If oldChar is in between 'a' and 'z'
char newChar = 'Z' - (oldChar - 'A'); // If oldChar is in between 'A' and 'Z'
```

See [this](http://www.asciitable.com/) for ASCII table.

You need to handle the situation like `oldChar` is a valid alphabet ((`a` <= oldChar and oldChar <= 'z') or (`A` <= oldChar and oldChar <= 'Z'))

See this code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>
#include <exception>

char char_invert(char x)
{
    if ((x >= 'a') and (x <= 'z'))
        return 'z' - (x - 'a');
    if ((x >= 'A') and (x <= 'Z'))
        return 'Z' - (x - 'A');
    throw std::runtime_error("Invalid Character");
}

std::string string_invert(std::string str)
{
    std::string result;
    for (auto& c: str)
        result.push_back(char_invert(c));
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::string example = "aBCDEFUVWXYZ";
    std::cout << example << std::endl;
    std::cout << string_invert(example) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this. explanation of code is in the comments.

```
//---generic: this supports any string buffer such as const char*.
void invertStrBuf(char* p_szArr, size_t p_size){

    for(size_t a = 0; a < p_size; a++){
        char item = p_szArr[a];
        char sc = item & ~0x20;      //force convert to upper case.
        if('A' <= sc && sc <= 'Z'){
            sc = 'Z' - (sc - 'A');  //invert letter
            p_szArr[a] = sc | (item & 0x20);  //change back to original case and then save.
        }
    }


}

//---std::string.
void invertStr(std::string& p_str){
    invertStrBuf(&p_str[0], p_str.size());
}


void main(){

    //---convert std::string
    std::string sVal = "abcZYX123&*(";
    invertStr(sVal);
    cout << "string: " << sVal << endl;


    // //---convert char buffer.
    // const char sampVal = "another 123 EXAMPLE +_\[]";
    // size_t sizeSampVal = strlen(sampVal);
    // char* charBuf = malloc(sizeSampVal+1);
    // memmove(charBuf, sampVal, sizeSampVal+1);

    // invertStrBuf(&charBuf[0], strlen(charBuf));

    // cout << "charBuf[]: " << charBuf << endl;

}
```